# Can't switch google cloud project on GAS Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-script-editor

I am not able to switch google cloud platform project in GAS editor.

What I am doing is…

1. Open the google sheet GAS editor
2. Open Resource --> Cloud Platform Project
3. Enter project number that I want to connect

With the process above, I was able to switch a cloud platform project but now it returns an error

**‘Project does not exist, or you need edit access to it.’**

I am using the same cloud project and same account(editor) that I used before and properly worked. I tried do the same with a owner account, but it didn’t work, either.

Also, this cloud project is not a default project nor a hidden project. (If it does, I guess it should not be able to access through GAS editor from the beginning)

I have checked documentation below, but it tells me only case when switching to a hidden project.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects

Does anyone have a solution or suggestion??

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: How was the account you are trying to switch to created?

Answer (score 3):

Problem Solved.

I figured out that OAuth IDs which are generated when make connection docs to the cloud project are not be deleted even though delete actual document files.

What I have done is...

1. Login Google Cloud Platform
2. Go to APIs&Services --> Credentials
3. On OAuth 2.0 client IDs, delete unnecessary contents from the list
4. Back to your docs and switch the cloud project.